# What is the name of a white-flowering shadow-loving plant?

Tags: identification

What is the name of the following plant? It is widely sold in plant shops in Germany as plant for shaded balconies, direct sun for longer time does kill it.

[image: Shadow living white-flowering plant]

Comment: I'm curious that you say direct sun kills this plant - its supposed to prefer a full sun position, see here https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/226818/euphorbia-hypericifolia-diamond-frost-(-inneuphe-pbr)/details

Comment: @Bamboo agreed. But I found a few lists where it was mentioned especially for shaded balconies.

Comment: @Bamboo It is just my experience: I had it in several planning pots and only those in half-shade survived, all others died. I must have been the sunshine duration, since all other factors (soil, spacing, irrigation) have been the same.

Comment: @B--rian same irrigation for plants in semi shade and full sun? I guess that explains a lot.

Comment: @Stephie A good point, I fully ignored that the soil humidity in shade and sun is different :-) So I guess the ones in the sun dried out then. It is funny that my professional gardener neighbor confirmed my hypotesis is the sun rather the amount of water.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an **euphorbia** hybrid (naming varies, including *E. hypericifolia*, *E. graminea*, or a hybrid with one of those species, or *Chamaesyce hypericifolia*), the trade name is **Diamond Frost**.

The German name is **Zauberschnee** (“magic snow”) and in recent years it has been a quite popular plant for container gardening and window boxes.